# Error while resolving field boosting on CD server

Tags: content-search

I am getting the below error on my CD servers. I have never run into this error before and not sure what it is trying to say. I have populated index schema and re-indexes. CM is working fine and search work on CM. The CD Solr and xConnect work on the CD (as I can hit the URLs).

It logs this for a few IDs. Thes ones referenced in this error are:
`/sitecore/templates/System/Templates/Sections/Appearance/Appearance/__Display name`

```
ERROR Error while resolving field boosting. Field={B5E02AD9-D56F-4C41-A065-A133DB87BDEB} Item=sitecore://web/{9FDCA07F-AE40-493D-B98D-017EBA0BD1BB}?lang=en&ver=1
Exception: System.NullReferenceException
Message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Source: Sitecore.ContentSearch
at  Sitecore.ContentSearch.Pipelines.ResolveBoost.ResolveFieldBoost.FieldDefinitionItemResolver.Process(ResolveFieldBoostArgs args)
at (Object , Object )
at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists)
at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
at Sitecore.Abstractions.CorePipelineWrapper.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args)
at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Boosting.PipelineBasedBoostingProvider.ResolveFieldBoosting(IIndexableDataField field)
at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Boosting.BoostingManager.ResolveFieldBoosting(IIndexableDataField field)
```

This is for Sitecore 9.1.1

Comment: Do these items exist in your database? Have you rebuilt the link databases?

Answer (score 0):

In our experience, we saw a similar error:

```
6236 23:00:31 ERROR Error while resolving field boosting. Field={5DD74568-4D4B-44C1-B513-0AF5F4CDA34F} Item=sitecore://web/{3045E73E-BC37-4B8E-8482-0639C847099B}?lang=en&ver=1
Exception: System.NullReferenceException
Message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Source: Sitecore.ContentSearch
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Pipelines.ResolveBoost.ResolveFieldBoost.FieldDefinitionItemResolver.Process(ResolveFieldBoostArgs args)
   at (Object , Object )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
   at Sitecore.Abstractions.CorePipelineWrapper.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Boosting.PipelineBasedBoostingProvider.ResolveFieldBoosting(IIndexableDataField field)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Boosting.BoostingManager.ResolveFieldBoosting(IIndexableDataField field)
```

This appears to be caused by installing a package prior to the templates being present, or by deleting a template of an existing item.

If the item in question gets published, it gets placed into a never ending loop that creates event queue records. This is a known Sitecore bug.

The solution is either to delete the item or supply the missing template.

Then you can run these SQL queries to identify and delete the circular publish records. Sitecore recommends that the maximum number should be less than 1000 in any of these tables.

```
SELECT Top 10 * FROM [EventQueue]
Order by Created
GO
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [History]
GO
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [EventQueue]
GO
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [PublishQueue]
GO
TRUNCATE TABLE [History];
GO
TRUNCATE TABLE [EventQueue];
GO
TRUNCATE TABLE [PublishQueue];
```

**Note that this SQL query will truncate the specified tables. Please test in a safe environment before running on production.**